# Python - Minus 5 days from a given date does not work properly

Tags: python

I have this definition which receives a string as input (e.g. 01 June 2013) and returns a string after subtracting 5 days from the input date. This doesn't seem to work properly if the date is in the end of the month.

```
def GetEffectiveDate(self, systemdate):
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(systemdate, '%d %B %Y') - timedelta(days = 5), '%d/%b/%Y')
```

For example, if the input is '01 June 2013', the output I'm expecting is '27/May/2013' but its returning '27/June/2013'. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and it works fine for me...

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is not right, at least according to your input. Change your output from `'%d/%b/%Y'` to `'%d/%B/%Y'`

```
return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(systemdate, '%d %B %Y') - timedelta(days = 5), '%d/%B/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it still doesn't change the month.

Comment: Please try it now after the edits

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as you expect in Python 2.7:

> > > systemdate = '01 June 2013'
> > >
> > > datetime.datetime.strftime( datetime.datetime.strptime(systemdate, '%d %B %Y') - datetime.timedelta(days = 5), '%d/%b/%Y')
> > >
> > > '27/May/2013'

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.3:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def GetEffectiveDate(systemdate):
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(systemdate, '%d %b %Y') - 
        timedelta(days = 5), '%d/%b/%Y')

print(GetEffectiveDate("1 June 2013"))
```

... produces the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '1 June 2013' does not match format '%d %b %Y'
```

... whereas changing the formatting code as suggested by @Bryan Moyles:

```
def GetEffectiveDate(systemdate):
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(systemdate, '%d %B %Y') - 
        timedelta(days = 5), '%d/%b/%Y')
```

... produces:

```
27/May/2013
```

... as expected.